# Can I use Dagger 2 in a Java EE project?

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, dagger, jsr330

My boss has researched about Dagger 2 and he would like me to use this in my JSF projects. I have seen many references about Dagger 2 and Android. But, is it possible to use this framework in a JSF web application?

Comment: I'm still studying this thing. Nothing is defined now, but I wonder what is the best way and less "traumatic" to integrate JSF and Dagger 2.

Comment: Why not CDI - Contexts and Dependency Injection for the Java EE platform instead which is provided out of the box by any Java EE compliant container in turn?

Comment: P.S. : CDI can, if necessary, also be installed/enabled on pure bare-bones Servlet containers like Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is possible** if your application server supports [JSR-330](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330). The subtitle to the official [Dagger documentation page](http://square.github.io/dagger/) is *a fast dependency injector for Android and Java*, it also says *building on standard `javax.inject` annotations (JSR-330)*.

Comment: Would be nice to also add some some additional info on why you should use it instead of plain cdi

Comment: @Kukeltje His boss wants him to, the rest is merely opinion. The documentation gives a number of restrictions, and it might be faster to "startup" but it's primary objective is to optimize away reflection run-time cost (which isn't particularly large in a modern server JIT).

Comment: Well, if this was so easy to find on their site, lets wait for he next question then: _"can someone tell me if I should use it and why (not)"_ ;-)

Comment: This is not enough for it to be useful.  Have you actually _tried_ doing this?

Comment: @Kukeltje there are three main reasons to use Dagger-2: 1) There is no faster DI implementation 2) Because of how it generates it's code, you can have compile time validation of your DI graph and 3) because Dagger2 is essentially the automation of hand rolled DI [without using reflection], the resulting code is very simple and can be well obfuscated. Now the drawbacks are obvious, it doesn't use reflection! Most people are familiar with DI having AOP type functionality, this of course is not the case, so if you want that you'll need to use AspectJ. Another drawback...

Comment: which is causing most of the problem I think, is that a lot of frameworks use AOP/reflective magic. Because Dagger2 must build the whole graph it can't work it's way past such magic (which should be pretty obvious). As an example I like the web framework Struts2 (similar to SpringMVC and probably a lot of others), well anything that is going to use conventions magic is going to be screwed, as far as using Dagger2 seamlessly anyways. The only way around this to have Dagger2 use a servlet to build it's dependencies and graph from a root and then, if your framework of choice has the capabilities;

Comment: have dagger build up a configuration for that framework and feed it externally, or have your framework access those resources externally. Really the only way that looks seamless for web applications would be to not use JEE and perhaps use a framework like Spark [sparkjava.com not to be confused with Apache Spark] and Jetty. So while you _could_ hack dagger2 into a JEE application it isn't likely to play nice, it would be like some weird growth.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, and not easily.

It does not work out of the box, and the necessary work to make it do so (essentially hooking on a listener) is not part of the official Dagger2 distribution.  This is probably because the focus of Dagger is applications (main methods) and Java EE already has CDI.

If you write your code carefully you can write code that works well with both as it is just a matter of which annotations that is actually acted upon.

Answer (score -3):

**It is possible.** Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Could you provide some more details, maybe some references to official docs ?

Comment: And also some additional info on why you should use it instead of plain cdi

Comment: It is possible but not really practical.